# django failed to load static image

Tags: html, django, django-staticfiles, pythonanywhere

I have my django app hosted on pythonanywhere. I am using weasyprint to generate a pdf and there is an image to be shown in my pdf. The error in the error log is "Failed to load image at /static/images/logo.png". When I try to open the same path as url, it shows me the image in the browser. Which means it is getting the path right but something else is wrong.

I have my static directory placed outside the app. And this path is added to the settings file.

My folder structure:

```
     my_app
     static
        |__ css
        |__ images
              |__ logo.png
        |__ js
     templates
        |__ my_app
              |__ pdf.html
```

settings.py:

```
STATIC_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS =[
    STATIC_DIR,
]
```

pdf.html:

```
{% load static %}
<td><img class="my_logo" src="{% static 'images/logo.png' %}" alt="Temporarily Unavailable"></td>
```

Comment: try "STATIC_URL = './static/'"

Comment: Rename STATIC_DIR to STATIC_ROOT. And remove it from STATICFILES_DIRS: STATICFILES_DIRS is the list of _source_ folders that will be scanned during `collectstatic` to fill _destination_ folder - STATIC_ROOT.

Comment: @IvanStarostin so actually STATICFILES_DIRS is correct, since this **is** where the source static files are located. What's missing is a STATIC_ROOT directory outside of the project and running `manage.py collectstatic` to copy the static files from the static directory inside the project repository to the location from where they are served.

Comment: `directory outside of the project` looks like OP does not have such a directory.

Comment: then OP should add such a directory. you should never serve static files on production from within your project (source code) directory. Your entire project directory should only be accessible by your app server (WSGI), but not to your web server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to make a pdf for the user to download, or are you trying to display a html file?

If you are using weasyprint to generate a pdf, then weasyprint will not try to access `http://yourwebsite/static/images/logo.png` to get the logo to put into the pdf. Instead it will try to access the file on your server at `/static/images/logo.png`.

If all you want to do is to have the logo in your pdf, you should instead get weasyprint to say put in the logo from `/home/username/path/to/your/logo/file.png` instead.

Comment: Thanks. But the error in the error log is "Failed to load image at http:/ /mywebsite/static/images/logo.png"
Tried using the path which you suggested still showing the error "Failed to load image at http:/ /mywebsite/home/username/static/images/logo.png"

Comment: Am able to do it using the absolute file path :
src="file:///home/username/static/images/logo.png"
but is it okay to hardcode it this way? Nothing else I tried seems to work.

Comment: weasy print could create the pdf by accessing the file system and not the website to get the logo. Or after weasy print has created the pdf, the pdf itself could try to load the logo from the website but not from a file system. It's unclear to me what you want to do

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the folder structure you are showing is what you use on your development machine and reflects your actual code repository.

Your settings are correct:

- `STATICFILES_DIRS` lists the directories (outside of the apps) where you put your static files
- `STATIC_URL` is the url used to prefix the static location, telling the server "any url that starts with this, you need to go fetch a static file".

What's missing is:

- `STATIC_ROOT`: where should `collectstatic` copy your static files to? This is normally a location outside of your project repository, sometimes even on an entirely different machine, where your web server will serve the static files from. In a simple deployment, it can be a /static directory at the same level as your project:

```
/home/myusername/my_project_www/
     |_ my_project/   <-- BASE_DIR (this is a git clone of your code)
          |_ my_project
                |_ settings.py
                |_ urls.py
          |_ app/
              |_ views.py
              |_ static/  <-- automatically used as source by Django
          |_ manage.py
          |_ static/  <-- added to STATICFILES_DIRS
          |_ ...
     |_ static/  <-- STATIC_ROOT all files will be copied and served from here
     |_ media/  <-- MEDIA_ROOT if users can upload files
```

In the above example, you would set `STATIC_ROOT = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), 'static'))` (one directory above BASE_DIR).

- Then you need to run `manage.py collectstatic` so that all static files are copied into that directory.
- And finally in the pythonanywhere console, in the **Static Files** section, you have to map the `/static/` **url** to the location of `STATIC_ROOT`, i.e. `/home/username/my_project_www/static/` for **path**. (Or if you're running your own server, you need to configure this in your nginx or apache configuration).

I've written a [blog post](https://www.dedi.co/blog/entries/2018/12/17/deploying-static-files-aws-django-part-1) about this.

Comment: Very well explained. Thank you. :)
Did the changes you have suggested and every other static file/image is rendered properly on the website...just not the one I have included in the pdf!

Comment: @VasundharaAgrawal didn't realise the image would be embedded in a pdf file, i.e. not downloaded as a link. Hard-coding the entire path is probably not a good idea, since it could break if you deploy on another system. But something like `src="file://{{ STATIC_ROOT }}images/logo.png"` would work, if you make sure you pass `STATIC_ROOT` as a context variable to your template rendering.

Comment: Okay. Thanks @dirkgroten :)

Comment: note that this `file://` will be a problem if one day you decide to host your static files (STATIC_ROOT) on a different system, e.g. S3 from Amazon. Because `file://` tells weazyprint to look on the local file system. But you'd have to look into the details of how weazyprint works to figure out how to write the `src` because it would have to be able to use a different storage class (not `DefaultFileStorage`).

Comment: Yeah that's what I was thinking.

Comment: I think the proper way to do this is to define your own url_fetcher to pass to weazyprint. django-weazyprint (are you using that?) has defined [its own](https://github.com/fdemmer/django-weasyprint/blob/master/django_weasyprint/utils.py) which will just open the file from source so you can just use `{% static 'images/logo.png' %}` and it will open the file from within your source directory.